# How to squash commits on that came from 2 different places?

Tags: git, github

Since I started to work on the same project from both my desktop and laptop, I've been facing a super annoying problem regarding the master branch history:

So I create a feature branch on the desktop, do work, and commit to remote.
Later that day, let's say when I'm at the train, I pull the branch on my laptop and commit more stuff, and when I finish I want to squash all the commits and merge the branch to master.
The problem is that squashing everything is impossible because some originated from A and some from B...

Of course I can simply merge the branch to master, but then it would be filled with "Continuing X branch" commits - and that's why I want to squash them all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in squashing if the both commits are from the office or one of them is from a different computer. You can follow your normal squashing procedure as if all commits were done from your desk.

---

Please note that you don't need to squash the commits in the feature branch. You could squash when merging:

```
git checkout main; 
git merge --squash feature_branch
```

This would create a single commit in `main` and keep all the intermediate commit in `feature_branch`.

Answer (score 0):

Squashing *is* possible, from any of your two clones (for example: from your laptop). You will just have to remember to run `git fetch` and start working on the correct commit when you go back to your other station (e.g: when you work from your desktop, run `git fetch` and switch to the correct commit/branch before coding some more).